# How to filter undefined value in javascript arrays?

Tags: javascript

`const values = dataSku.map(sku => {return map.skuInfo[sku].description})`

Here, there is some posibility that map.skuInfo[sku] can be null/undefined and I need to filter it. How would it be possible ?

Comment: Use an `if` statement?

Comment: [`Array.prototype.filter()` (link: MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) - e.g. `const myFilteredArray = myArray.filter(Boolean)` (don't necessarily use `Boolean` like I show but provide an actual comparison, even though that works filtering out "falsy" values)

Comment: Can it be other *falsey* values, or specifically `undefined`?

Comment: With `Array.filter()` instead of `Array.map()`?

Comment: not existing in the map, so i assume undefined

Answer (score 13):

Sounds like you want `.filter`. It's a higher order function like `.map`.

```
const values = dataSku
    .filter(item => item.description !== undefined)
```

I'm not sure your exact data structure but [check it out here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)! It filters out all non-truthy return values.

Answer (score 2):

This will solve your problem -

```js
const values = dataSku.map(sku => map.skuInfo[sku]}).filter(skuInfo => typeof skuInfo !== "undefined").map(skuInfo => skuInfo.description);
```

Answer (score 1):

Can be done like this:

```
const values = dataSku.map(sku => {
    if (!map.skuInfo[sku]) return;
    return map.skuInfo[sku].description
})
```

Will return out of the function if `map.skuInfo[sku]` is falsey.

Answer (score 0):

You can something like as under

```
const filterNotNullAndUndefined = (sku)  => (sku?.description !== null  && sku?.description !== undefined);
const filterNotNUllAndUndefinedAndNonEmpty = (sku) => (sku?.description)

const sku = [
    {id: 1, 'description': '1'},
    {id: 2, 'description': null},
    {id: 3, 'description': undefined},
    {id: 4, 'description': ''},
    null,
    undefined
];

const result1 = sku?.filter(filterNotNUllAndUndefinedAndNonEmpty);
const result2 = sku?.filter(filterNotNullAndUndefined);

console.log(result1);
console.log(result2);
```

Comment: `filterNotNullAndUndefined` could be shorter: `sku => sku?.description ?? false`

Comment: oh yes totally missed `Nullish coalescing operator (??)`